# Set ID as a number in layout

Tags: java, android

How can I do `view.setId(123)` in the xml layout?

`android:id="123"` doesn't work, and `android:id="@+id/123"` would add it into the IDs file

**Edit:** I need to set the ID to a number because I'm setting it to a lot of views and I want to initiate them with a loop

Comment: What's the issue with adding it to the IDs file?

Comment: I'm doing this to a lot of views and I want to initiate them with a loop

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're doing something not intended. It's not possible to do it like you want, but there's a little workaround for that.

The most easy would be to define an array of these ids

```
static final int[] IDS = {R.id.id1, R.id.id2, ...};
```

or by using xml `TypeArray`

```
<resources>
    <array name="ids">
        <item>@id/id1</item>
        <item>@id/id2</item>
        ...
    </array>
</resources>
```

```
TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.ids);
for (int i = 0; i < ta.length(); i++)
    findViewById(ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
ta.recycle();
```

But better consider refactoring your code to not have the need of using this.